# How to unmarshall a json file with nested objects which can be different from eachother in Golang

Tags: json, go

With a json file that looks something like this, where someone can only have one social but it could be different depending on the person, how would I unmarshal this into a struct.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 14,
    "occupation": "Builder",
    "social": {
        "facebook": "Bob_the_builder"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 14,
    "occupation": "Builder",
    "social": {
        "twitter": "Alice_the_builder"
  }
]
```

My current struct variables looks like this.

```
type User struct {
   Name String 'json:"name"'
   Age int 'json:"age"'
   Occupation String 'json:"occupation"'
   Social Social 'json:"social"'
}

type Social struct {
  Facebook String 'json:"facebook"'
  Twitter String 'json:"twitter"'
}
```

Is this the correct way to unmarshall the json or will it fail as the 'Social' struct wants two different strings one for Facebook and one for Twitter. Is there a better way to unmarshall a json like this?

Comment: This is the correct way (assuming that syntax and other errors are fixed).

Comment: Your Go code has syntax errors and your JSON has syntax errors, but this is the correct way. The unused `Social` keys well end up being emptystring (`""`). If you do any marshalling you would need the `omitempty` tag.

Answer (score 2):

The example you provided should work, it will just leave one of your strings empty.

If you want to replace `Social` with 2 different structs, you can make `Social` an interface which both new structs implement. Then use [`json.RawMessage`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage) to delay the unmarshalling of the json in `social`. This is the example given in the godocs:

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    type Color struct {
        Space string
        Point json.RawMessage // delay parsing until we know the color space
    }
    type RGB struct {
        R uint8
        G uint8
        B uint8
    }
    type YCbCr struct {
        Y  uint8
        Cb int8
        Cr int8
    }

    var j = []byte(`[
    {"Space": "YCbCr", "Point": {"Y": 255, "Cb": 0, "Cr": -10}},
    {"Space": "RGB",   "Point": {"R": 98, "G": 218, "B": 255}}
]`)
    var colors []Color
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &colors)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error:", err)
    }

    for _, c := range colors {
        var dst interface{}
        switch c.Space {
        case "RGB":
            dst = new(RGB)
        case "YCbCr":
            dst = new(YCbCr)
        }
        err := json.Unmarshal(c.Point, dst)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("error:", err)
        }
        fmt.Println(c.Space, dst)
    }
}
```

In this example they use a string to indicate as which struct to unmarshall `Point`. In your case you may need to first unmarshall `social` as `map[string]interface{}` and determine which type should be used based on the fields. Or add a `socialType` field to the `User` struct.

Comment: Cheers thank you I was getting confused if it would fill it as an empty string or not but that answers it.